# How i can fetch data from an Api in Json in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

How i can Fetch data from an Json Api like that:

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

```
responseBody.title
```

i Already have this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await 
client.GetAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Your life will get massively easier if you spend 15 minutes looking into http://QuickType.io

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library for working with JSON data.
You can use serialization/deserialization or LINQ to JSON methods

For example based on your code:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

// LINQ to JSON method
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
int userId = int.Parse(jsonObject["userId"].ToString());
int id = int.Parse(jsonObject["id"].ToString());
string title = jsonObject["title"].ToString();
bool completed = bool.Parse(jsonObject["completed"].ToString());
```